# How to use minAreaRect() function without getting error?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem that has ruined my project:

```
def extract_candidate_rectangles(image, contours):
    rectangles = []
    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        min_rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)

        if validate_contour(min_rect):
            x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
            plate_img = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            if is_max_white(plate_img):
                copy = image.copy()
                cv.rectangle(copy, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                rectangles.append(plate_img)
                cv.imshow("candidates", copy)
                cv.waitKey(0)
    return rectangles
```

and the error is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muhammad/Coding/Python/PlateDetectionCodes/PlateDetection/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    plates = extract_candidate_rectangles(resized.copy(), contours)
  File "/home/muhammad/Coding/Python/PlateDetectionCodes/PlateDetection/extractor.py", line 65, in extract_candidate_rectangles
    min_rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'convexHull'
```

I'll be glad if anyone can help!

Comment: check if the `contours` that you are passing as an argument is in the right format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace shows you the line in which the error occured:

```
min_rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)
```

Now, you want to take a look at this line of the error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'convexHull'
```

especially this part:

```
Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'convexHull'
```

I assume that *cv.minAreaRect* internally calls *convexHull*.
OpenCV uses the *Assert* function to make sure that the parameters passed into a function are in the correct format.
Here, either the *cnt* is empty (total >= 0 is not satisfied) or the format of the points inside the contour array is neither CV_32F (32 bit float) or CV_32S (32 bit signed integer).